# Count the total number ways to reach the nth stair using step 1, 2 or 3 but the step 3 can be taken only once

Tags: algorithm, graph-layering

For any given value N we have to find the number of ways to reach the top while using steps of 1,2 or 3 but we can use 3 steps only once.
for example if n=7
then possible ways could be

[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

[1,1,1,1,1,2]

etc but we cannot have [3,3,1] or [1,3,3]

I have managed to solve the general case without the constraint of using 3 only once with dynamic programming as it forms a sort of fibonacci series

```py
 def countWays(n) : 
    res = [0] * (n + 1) 
    res[0] = 1
    res[1] = 1
    res[2] = 2

    for i in range(3, n + 1) : 
        res[i] = res[i - 1] + res[i - 2] + res[i - 3] 

    return res[n]
```

how do I figure out the rest of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `res0[n]` be the number of ways to reach `n` steps *without* using a 3-step, and let `res1[n]` be the number of ways to reach `n` steps after having used a 3-step.

`res0[i]` and `res1[i]` are easily calculated from the previous values, in a manner similar to your existing code.

This is an example of a pretty common technique that is often called "graph layering".  See, for example: [Shortest path in a maze with health loss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50319901/shortest-path-in-a-maze-with-health-loss/50321206#50321206)

Comment: I'm not sure that is sufficient, since you do not per se first use a 3-step. You thus need to find out *per* stair how many steps there were, and thus multiply with that number, since you can insert the 3-step everywhere in the stair.

Comment: I didn't say you had to use the 3-step *first*.  `res1[i] = res0[i-3] + res1[i-2] + res1[i-1]`.  The first term represents using the 3-step from `i-3` to `i`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the recurrence Matt Timmermans shared, `res1[i] = res0[i-3] + res1[i-2] + res1[i-1]`, returns the same results as your function.  Please consider voting up an answer that's teaching something new :)

Answer (score 0):

Let us first ignore the three steps here. Imagine that we can only use steps of one and two. Then that means that for a given number *n*. We know that we can solve this with *n* steps of *1* (one solution), or *n-2* steps of *1* and one step of *2* (*n-1* solutions); or with *n-4* steps of *1* and two steps of *2*, which has *n-2×n-3/2* solutions, and so on.

The number of ways to do that is related to the Fibonacci sequence. It is clear that the number of ways to construct `0` is one: just the empty list `[]`. It is furthermore clear that the number of ways to construct `1` is one as well: a list `[1]`. Now we can proof that the number of ways *W<sub>n</sub>* to construct *n* is the sum of the ways *W<sub>n-1</sub>* to construct *n-1* plus the number of ways *W<sub>n-2</sub>* to construct *n-2*. The proof is that we can add a one at the end for each way to construct *n-1*, and we can add 2 at the end to construct *n-2*. There are no other options, since otherwise we would introduce duplicates.

The number of ways *W<sub>n</sub>* is thus the same as the Fibonacci number *F<sub>n+1</sub>* of *n+1*. We can thus implement a Fibonacci function with caching like:

```
cache = [0, 1, 1, 2]
def fib(n):
    for i in range(len(cache), n+1):
        cache.append(cache[i-2] + cache[i-1])
    return cache[n]
```

So now how can we fix this for a given step of three? We can here use a divide and conquer method. We know that if we use a step of three, it means that we have:

```
1 2 1 … 1 2 3 2 1 2 2 1 2 … 1
\____ ____/   \_______ _____/
     v                v
  sum is m    sum is n-m-3
```

So we can iterate over *m*, and each time multiply the number of ways to construct the left part (`fib(m+1)`) and the right part (`fib(n-m-3+1)`) we here can range with *m* from `0` to `n-3` (both inclusive):

```
def count_ways(n):
    total = 0
    for m in range(0, n-2):
        total += fib(m+1) * fib(n-m-2)
    return total + fib(n+1)
```

or more compact:

```
def count_ways(n):
    return fib(n+1) + sum(fib(m+1) * fib(n-m-2) for m in range(0, n-2))
```

This gives us:

```
>>> count_ways(0)  # ()
1
>>> count_ways(1)  # (1)
1
>>> count_ways(2)  # (2) (1 1)
2
>>> count_ways(3)  # (3) (2 1) (1 2) (1 1 1)
4
>>> count_ways(4)  # (3 1) (1 3) (2 2) (2 1 1) (1 2 1) (1 1 2) (1 1 1 1)
7
```